# Codeigniter match regex except particular strings

Tags: codeigniter, routes

i'm rewriting the url, `http://www.sitename.com/controller/function/parameter` to `http://www.sitename.com/parameter` which i'm doing this using,

```
$route['(:any)'] = "home/index/$1";
```

in router.php. But i want to exclude `http://www.sitename.com/administrator` and `http://www.sitename.com/adminlogin` from `routes.php` from rewriting this URL. I tried many combinations, but nothing worked. Please help in doing this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-regex solution

Just put the rules to those exception cases **above** the 'any' case you have.

```
$route['administrator/(:any)'] = "administrator/$1";
$route['adminlogin/(:any)'] = "adminlogin/$1";

$route['(:any)'] = "home/index/$1";
```

I prefer doing a non-regex way because it will look much neater in case you decide to add more exception urls.

Comment: It is working for administrator and adminlogin but not for administrator/function and adminlogin/function :(

Comment: You didn't specify you'd need those too. Anyway, then just add two more: `$route['administrator/(:any)']` and `$route['adminlogin/(:any)']`. In fact, if might work only with these two (not tested though).

Comment: $route['administrator/(:any)'] = "administrator/$1";
$route['adminlogin/(:any)'] = "adminlogin/$1";

Thanks. This one works. But otherwise login is not happening.